# Change data source on request

Tags: html, image, http, url, datasource

I'm setting up an editor for sending emails and it needs to support inline attachments.

I'm trying to avoid having to programmatically change aspects of the source HTML generated by TinyMCE, but I have an issue.

The inline attachments are added like so:

```
<img src="cid:image001.png@01D0D069.FAD8F390">
```

Naturally this doesn't work in the browser, but does in the email.  However in order to avoid having to change the HTML, I need the browser to "think" this is a valid link.  I then need to override the request to the image and supply alternative (valid) data back.  All the while retaining the "cid" as the source of the image.

Is it possible to do this?  I've been looking for ways to handle outgoing URLs, but so far no luck.